# User Interface for Leap Motion C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, user-interface, windows-forms-designer, leap-motion

I have created an app for sign recognition using Visual Studio.The code is written in C++. It works perfectly on Console Application (where I have done a litlle console menu, etc)
Now, I want to make a simply interface for my app, where it would be possible interact with the mouse instead of using console input.
I have tried using Windows Form with C++, but it doesn't work with my c++ leap motion code.

Could you advise me about any program or method for make a simply interface for my programme writte in C++ which use Leap Motion? Only for use the mouse, buttons, textbox, imagesbox,etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Qt library [1] which have a designer (QDesigner) that simplifies the creation of interfaces and allows to add textboxs, labels, texts, etc.

I suggest you to start from the tutorial available on the official website [2] and then extend it integrating your code.

[1] https://www.qt.io/

[2] https://wiki.qt.io/Basic_Qt_Programming_Tutorial

Comment: Thank you for your answer @FrancescoArgese , I have been seeing something about Qt, but it bring problems when use the Leap Motion library. You know something for the Leap Motion library and interface? thank you very much

Comment: What types of problems? I've not yet working directly on Leap Motion API but I know that it defines a listener to allow receiving data related to position  and rotation of fingers. It can be integrated in a Qt application or in a Windows Form application.